# parse string array using retrofit2

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

Can you please help me in parsing `{"array" : ["123", "345", "567", "789"]}` via Retrofit2.

I have tried this way,

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>(); 
public void setArray(ArrayList<String> array){
this.array = array;
}
public ArrayList<String> getArray(){
return this.array;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

Change your getArray method like this

```
public ArrayList<String> getArray(){
    return this.array;
}
```

you forgot to return ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

u can use from [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library for parsing to json object or array like this:

```
JsonArray version = new JsonParser().parse(strResponse).getAsJsonArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse to array from retrofit:

```
@GET("methodThatReturnsArray")
Call<ArrayList<String>> methodThatReturnsArray();
```

now you have to call Synchronous would look like:

```
Call<ArrayList<String>> call = retrofitService.methodThatReturnsArray();
Response response = call.execute();
ArrayList<String> arrayOfStrings = response.body();
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which converter you are using but for Strings, you can use Scalars [in here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/scalars) . Hopefully it helps to you :)